# Solving Polynomials using Newtons Method

Tags: complex-analysis, newton-raphson

I am using Newton's Method to solve approximate complex zeros of polynomials.

$$x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{0})}{f'(x_{0})}$$

Take the case of a cubic, with three solutions.

My issue is, that three different, random initial points, $(x_{0},y_{0})$
, $(x_{1},y_{1})$, and $(x_{2},y_{2})$, may all converge to one single point, or two different points, but not find all three complex zeros.

Are there ways to optimize the initial points chosen such that it is guaranteed they will converge to the three different zeros of the function.

Failing that, are there other methods that can be used to approximate zeros of polynomials.

Comment: For a cubic polynomial $p(x)$, once you find one zero $p(x_1)=0$ you can use Euclidean division to divide the original polynomial by $x-x_1$ and that gives you a quadratic equation which you can solve exactly. Does this help?

Comment: For a cubic polynomial you can actually use the Cardano formula to solve the equation exactly. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation.

For higher degree polynomials it's a complicated matter to approximate all roots. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms#Roots_of_polynomials

Comment: @StinkingBishop the example of a cubic was just that, an example. A relevant solution to this problem should be applicable to higher degree polynomials, where an exact solution cannot be found.